# Jquery get preference first before loading style sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a web platform where user can select dark mode or normal mode. This preference is saved in the database in the backend.

I want to load this parameter first then apply the appropriate style sheet so that after the UI is loaded it shows the mode (dark or normal) the user has selected.

Is there a way to do the api call first then apply the css style sheet?

Comment: If it's stored in the backend, then just read it in the backend when the page loads and only render the relevant css link tag.  No need for "an api call"

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry I may have worded it incorrectly. the preference is stored in the database and is specific to each user. so I have to run an api call to get the preference.

Comment: It sounds like you’re viewing your api call as a separate event (user starts a new session with your server; server sends the initial page content, the user’s browser then contacts the server to request the CSS file based on a preference stored in your server’s database; server sends the light or dark CSS file). Why not use the more common method and keep the preference info at the browser (cookie or local storage)? You could include both light and dark information in your CSS file (colors don’t usually take up much space) and users could use dark on their mobile and light on their home PC.

Comment: How are you generating your pages in the first place?  Are they static html/js files or do you use something like php or asp.net?